# Дудосят Postgres

Tags: postgresql, сервер, devops, vds

Запустил при помощи docker-compose базу данных Postgres на платном VDS сервере.
Заметил в логах, что кто-то постоянно пытается (при чём с разных IP) авторизоваться в моей базе данных под пользователем "postgres" с неверным паролем.

Я использую другую учётную запись для базы данных и при помощи pg_hba.conf ограничил доступ кроме моей учётной записи.

```
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 21:58:20.502 UTC [223] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 21:59:39.493 UTC [228] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "115.156.92.54", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 21:59:40.041 UTC [229] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "115.156.92.54", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 21:59:40.583 UTC [230] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "115.156.92.54", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:27.779 UTC [233] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:28.858 UTC [234] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:29.938 UTC [235] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:31.018 UTC [236] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:32.098 UTC [237] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:33.178 UTC [238] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
postgres_1       | 2024-03-02 22:00:36.261 UTC [239] FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "151.80.33.214", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption
```

Мне не нравятся в этих логах то, что постоянно кто-то пытается авторизоваться с неверным паролем, думаю что это всё же может быть небезопасно.

Что делать в такой ситуации? Пробовать новую БД с другими портами создавать?
Или использовать другой способ авторизации пользователя.

p.s.
я 100 раз перепроверил свои сервисы, все используют ту учётную запись, которую нужно (не postgres).
Даже когда я все контейнеры с сервисами останавливаю, кроме postgres, всё равно кто-то ломится ко мне.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас база смотрит в интернет...

Comment: Порт открыт, мне нужно дашборды в графане строить из моей БД.

Comment: А всё что смотрит в интернет будут обязательно дудосить. Тот же SSH.

Comment: Если всё же надо, чтобы порт смотрел в интернет, возможно port knocking в помощь

Comment: Как я понял можно список белых ip мне забить.
Но я тогда не понимаю, как мне подключаться к datasource моей БД в Grafana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я хотел открытый порт БД только для того, чтобы строить dashboard в Grafana. Для того, чтобы строить dashboard, нужно подключить datasoruce(База данных). Я думал, что нужно указывать прямой хост моего сервера, где находится база данных.
Оказывается, если Grafana тоже запущена на сервере (в docker контейнере), то можно в dashboard указывать не сам ip сервера, а "название_контейнера:порт" (в моём примере это так - postgres:5432).
Соответственно, у меня сейчас закрытый порт на внешку у базы данных и при этом могу строить всё что можно в Grafana.